# Losing UK Residence Permit when not resident for a year

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I have a UK Bio-metric Residence Permit & I will be out of the UK for one year.
Is it possible that I will lose my permit?
My wife is a UK citizen.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. On returning, you will may to convince the border agent that you are returning permanently to your center of life, which is in the United Kingdom. Since you are within the 2 year limit, and depending on the reasons you were away for so long, it shouldn't be a problem as long as you are genuinely a returning resident.

Comment: "will may to": should that have been "will need to"?